# Binary Operation in Group

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

The problem is actually from a high school exam (IBHL) and is supposed to be elementary: A group $G$ of order $9$ contains distinct elements $x$ and $y$ such that $x\not= y^2$. Express $(xy)^2$ as a product of two of the elemetns $x,y,x^2 ,y^2$ and hence show that $xy=yx$.

I knew $(xy)^2=y^2x^2$ and that $xy$ has order $3$ , but i failed to show that $x$ commutes with $y$. Please helps, thanks!

Comment: How do you know that $(xy)^2 = y^2x^2$? It follows once you know $x$ and $y$ commute, but I'm not sure you're reasoning accurately.

Comment: do you really mean $x\neq y^2$? And this is highschool?

Comment: hi pjs36: My argument is as follows: The order of $xy$ can only br $1,3$ or $9$ by Lagrange. If the order is $9$, then $G$ is cyclic and hence abelian, so that $(xy)^3=x^3y^3=1$, contradicting that $9$ is the order. If the order is $1$, then $xy=1$ and hence $y^{-1}=x$. But it is easy to show that $x \not\in \langle y\rangle$, so $y^{-1}$ cannot equal $x$ and thus the order of $xy$ is $3$. Now $(xy)^3=1$. Therefore $(xy)^{-1}=(xy)^2=y^{-1}x^{-1}=y^2x^2$

Comment: hi Zelos, yes and it's a practice problem in the IBDP higher level exam.

Answer (score 1):

In general you can show a group $G$ of order $p^2$ ( with $p$ prime) is abelian, that is because $p$-groups have non-trivial center, so the center $Z(G)$ can have order $p$ or $p^2$ via Lagrange's theorem .But it also holds that if $\frac{G}{Z(G)}$ is cyclic then the group is abelian. So $Z(G)$ cannot be of order $3$ since otherwise $\frac{G}{Z(G)}$ would be of order $3$ and therefore cyclic, which in turn would make $G$ abelian, contradicting $Z(G)\neq G$. So $G$ is abelian.

Hence $(xy)^2=x^2y^2$